# Business event handling

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, event-handling

I am working on a labour management service that allows it's user to enter their timesheets, allows manager to modify those timesheets and sync attendance over web connectors or web services. Now, we need to have a feature that sends users email if there total week hours are more than weekly hours limit. It's event driven like as soon as added shifts for the user is more than limit, send an email unlike scheduler jobs.

I'd like to know some best practices that I can use to achieve this. I don't want to get into my existing code and add number of lines in existing code, I'd like to accomplish it with as little as possible change in existing code base and add code only related to trigger an event and rest event handler should be taking care of sending emails.

Techs used:
Spring4, Java7

PS: 
I know it's like a story and it may not suited for StackOverflow, please feel free to move this question to a place in SO network where it fits well.

Comment: why not use a queue based mechanism, when limit is passed add a message to the queue, then a scheduler will pickup from this queue and send emails